# Low budget zombie movie/show shot in 2000's, drifter tries to get a girl who is kidnapped by raider gang

Tags: story-identification, zombie

A few years back I rented a movie from Netflix’s mail order movie service (or multi part mini series I can’t quite remember.)  The plot involved some sort of drifter with an overly gruff voice who was trying to get a girl back who was kidnapped by a raider gang (similar to *Mad Max*). The leader of the raiders looked like the Ethan supple from *My name is Earl*.
Details I remember:

- The zombies talked and could fight like people (punching, kicking, etc.)
- It was very low budget (it looked like they used Halloween costume weapons for props).
- It appeared to be shot in the early 2000’s.

I don’t remember too much else about it other than a military plot point with someone stuck in the desert earlier on in the film (or show).

Comment: _"it was very low budget it looked like they used Halloween costume weapons for props"_ nothing rings bells but that line immediately makes me think of Troma, could it be one of their's? something like [Zombiegeddon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCgI78aYilU) maybe.

Comment: That wasn’t it. I can’t remember if it was a movie with one or two sequels, or a multi disc movie/mini series.

Comment: @SidneyA You can check your rental history from Netflix - Account - Under Settings - DVD rental activity.  Will show last 100, but at the bottom there will be a Show All button. Tedious, I know, but maybe the DVD image will ring a bell.